# What is "HP ENVY"?

Tags: hp-envy

What, really, is an HP ENVY?

- [HP ENVY 4500](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/printers/hp-envy-4500-e-all-in-one-printer) is a printer
- [HP ENVY 15](http://store.hp.com/us/en/mdp/Laptops/envy-15-204072--1) is a laptop
- HP ENVY 750z is a desktop
- HP ENVY 24 is a monitor

Based on this I might as well say that an "ENVY" is the name of every product made by HP. Except they make all these things in products not branded ENVY as well. Like HP Officejet printers, or HP Pavillion laptops/desktops/monitors.

When I see something branded "ENVY", the only thing I know for sure is that it is *a product* made by HP.

So what makes them decide to call something ENVY?

Comment: It’s a brand. HP acquired it together with Voodoo PC. And that’s really all there is to it. Marketing.

Comment: Whats a GM Chevrolet? an Impala, a Cruze, a Corvette.....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chevrolet_vehicles

Answer (score 3):

Its a product series, mostly consumer by the looks of it. Its literally all on wikipedia already.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Envy

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not say anything to distinguish what makes a product an Envy, though HP has other consumer products with non-Envy brands.

Comment: Its a business decision. Same way dell has Vostro/Inspiron/XPS/Alienware and Lenovo has G/Y/Thinkpad.